# How to use different jest.config.js for unit and component tests?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I am trying to create a separate suite of tests for component level testing of an app.

In this separate suite, I will need a custom test environment that bootstraps some persistence layer mocks and these tests will be housed in a separate folder in my project structure from my unit tests.

e.g. the unit tests will be nearby the code in `__tests__` folders while the component tests will be in a top-level `tests/` directory.

I already have most of my jest.config.js setup, but when I added the `projects` section to override some of the fields, specifically `testMatch` and `testEnvironment` it completely disregarded my configuration specified in global.

Now I've been reading that the `projects` configuration is mostly about monorepo setups, so I don't think that's the right approach.

Ideally I could just have a separate `jest.config.js` in my `tests/` directory, but I don't see how to set that up if that even works.

Any insight into this problem would be helpful. Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to specify separate projects in `package.json`

```
"jest": {
    "projects": [
        "<rootDir>/jest.unit.config.js",
        "<rootDir>/tests/jest.component.config.js"
    ]
}
```

This allowed me to run either `jest` on its own and it will run all projects or if I wanted to specify a specific config to run I could run `jest --projects jest.unit.config.js` and it will just run that specific project.

I could also add a scripts section to my package.json to run them more easily.

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest", 
    "test:unit": "jest --projects tests/jest.unit.config.js",
    "test:component": "jest --projects jest.component.config.js"
}
```

Comment: If I run just `npm run jest`, it can't find the config file. How did you solve that?

Answer (score 15):

To specify different config files you can use the [`--config`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#--configpath) option.

For example if you have a `tests/jest.config.js` file configuration for your component tests and a `jest.config.js` file for your unit tests, you can configure the scripts in your `package.json` so that they look something like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "tests:unit": "jest --config=jest.config.js",
    "tests:component": "jest --config=tests/jest.config.js"
}
```

Comment: Will jest notice and pick them both up if I just run jest at the top level, then?